# Homomorphisms: What am I missing here?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I am considering a homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb{Z}_{12} \to \Bbb{Z}_{30}$ by defining $\phi(1)=7 \pmod{30}$ - mapping a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ to a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_{30}$. Then noting that $1 \equiv 25 \equiv5 \cdot 5 \pmod{12}$, but then $\phi(5\cdot 5)=\phi(5)+\cdots +\phi(5)=5\phi(5)=5\cdot 5\phi(1)=5\cdot 5\cdot 7=175=25 \pmod{30}$ imply $\phi(1)=\phi(5\cdot 5)=25 \pmod{30}$. Which cannot be since $\phi$ must be a function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is simply a proof that there does not exist any homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb{Z}_{12} \to \Bbb{Z}_{30}$ such that $\phi(1)=7 \pmod{30}$.

Note that you never actually defined the map $\phi$ or proved that your definition gives a homomorphism.  You just defined what you wanted $\phi(1)$ to be, and assumed that $\phi$ was a homomorphism in order to compute other values of $\phi$.

Comment: I have also argued with myself in my head that I haven't proved $\phi$ is a function. I think I misunderstood the book I'm reading when it said the images of the other elements completely depends on the image of $1$. But, then it followed that we still have to consider a list of possible candidates for image of $1$. I think this agrees with your answer. Thank you! I thought I was going mad, for a moment here. lol.